# Lion OS - brew update returns "Failure while executing..."

Tags: git, osx-lion, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to update my brew, when I set

> brew update

I get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

or

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

What's the problem with Git? How to update brew if this way doesn't work?

Comment: Guys, what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 13):

This is caused by an old bug in the `update` code that has long since been fixed. However, the nature of the bug requires that you do the following:

```
cd $(brew --repository)
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

If `brew doctor` still complains about uncommitted modifications, also run this command:

```
cd $(brew --repository)    
git clean -fd
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution suggested on the "Common Issues" page under [`brew update` complains about untracked working tree files](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues#brew-update-complains-about-untracked-working-tree-files). I had a similar issue and this resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first error you get indicates the following: you have a file `Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb` that you have modified in your working directory and those modifications have not been committed. You cannot have uncommitted changes when you do a pull, which `brew update` does implicitly. You must obey the instructions given in the error text: Before you do brew update, [commit](http://gitref.org/basic/#commit) all modified files, including `imagemagick.rb`.